# How to implement a YOLO model using TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, yolo

I want to implement a face detection model using TensorFlow. I have a dataset downloaded from Google's OID. I have prepared the annotation file as required in the YOLO. But I don't understand how to convert the annotations to the required output tensors.

Is learning Darknet a simpler option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer to use darknet rather than Tensorflow. However, use these [codes](https://github.com/wizyoung/YOLOv3_TensorFlow) to build YOLOV3 in TensorFlow.

Also, take a look at this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/track-vehicles-and-people-using-yolov3-and-tensorflow-4f3d0e5b1b5f)

Comment: I have a windows system.

Comment: You can use the code in windows too.

Comment: Can me tell me how? I followed a video on youtube using cmake but it didn't work.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/track-vehicles-and-people-using-yolov3-and-tensorflow-4f3d0e5b1b5f

Comment: Thank you for the help